# Could not open websocket with bokeh on nginx

Tags: nginx, flask, websocket, bokeh

I am trying to use [bokeh](https://bokeh.org/) on a digitalocean droplet, which runs ubuntu 18.04 with LAMP stack and reverse-proxy nginx (set up as described in these tutorials [Initial server setup](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-18-04), [LAMP setup](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-ubuntu-18-04), [nginx as reverse-proxy](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-web-server-and-reverse-proxy-for-apache-on-one-ubuntu-18-04-server) ).

I used these tutorials ([1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04) and [2](https://rbtechblog.com/blog/deploy_bokeh_app)) for setting up the bokeh part.

It looks like that it almost works but I get some error messages in the Browser console, of which I do not know how to resolve them.

This is the output in the browser console:

```
Bokeh: BokehJS not loaded, scheduling load and callback at Date ...
Bokeh: injecting script tag for BokehJS library:  /bokeh/static/js/bokeh.min.js?v=547e7d2591695b654def5914eef697fa 
Bokeh: injecting script tag for BokehJS library:  /bokeh/static/js/bokeh-widgets.min.js?v=423bf6bb32b8def9b7c9df74817506e4 
Bokeh: injecting script tag for BokehJS library:  /bokeh/static/js/bokeh-tables.min.js?v=5f778b8a005d8538b5b14598ec45fc16 
Bokeh: injecting script tag for BokehJS library:  /bokeh/static/js/bokeh-gl.min.js?v=be19384f76795da42f52380e7b5fd473 
Bokeh: all BokehJS libraries/stylesheets loaded 
Bokeh: BokehJS plotting callback run at Date ...
[bokeh] setting log level to: 'info' 
Bokeh: all callbacks have finished 
Source map error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: https://my-domain.com/bokeh/static/js/bokeh.min.js?v=547e7d2591695b654def5914eef697fa
Source Map URL: bokeh.min.js.map 2
Source map error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: https://my-domain.com/bokeh/static/js/bokeh-widgets.min.js?v=423bf6bb32b8def9b7c9df74817506e4
Source Map URL: bokeh-widgets.min.js.map
Source map error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: https://my-domain.com/bokeh/static/js/bokeh-tables.min.js?v=5f778b8a005d8538b5b14598ec45fc16
Source Map URL: bokeh-tables.min.js.map
Source map error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: https://my-domain.com/bokeh/static/js/bokeh-gl.min.js?v=be19384f76795da42f52380e7b5fd473
Source Map URL: bokeh-gl.min.js.map
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://my-domain.com/bokeh/ws?bokeh-protocol-version=1.0&bokeh-session-id=Zts1wLAtCSZoHUr7Nx3UfIFdUAgGOMFdFA8JfEuDmEzM. 
[bokeh] Failed to connect to Bokeh server Error: Could not open websocket 
    pull_session https://my-domain.com/bokeh/static/js/bokeh.min.js?v=547e7d2591695b654def5914eef697fa:31
[bokeh] Lost websocket 0 connection, 1006 () 
Error: Could not open websocket 
[bokeh] Websocket connection 0 disconnected, will not attempt to reconnect
```

This is part of the nginx conf file:

```
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }

    # reverse proxy to embedded bokeh apps
    location /bokeh/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5100;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }
```

I guess there is something missing in the conf file, but I cannot figure out what.

Comment: What does the bokeh server log show? Is there no connection attempt registered there at all? Or did one make it past nginx, but get refused by the bokeh server? (probably need to set `--allow-websocket-origin` then)

Comment: I checked the nginx log and there are no errors. `allow-websocket-origin` is set in the script with `kws = {'port': 5100, 'prefix': '/bokeh', 'allow_websocket_origin': ['xxx.xxx.xxx.xx']}` with the public IP address of my droplet. I will check the bokeh server log, but I have to figure out how to first

Comment: Unless you are ultimately connecting with the literal ip address in the URL bar, that won't work. You need to whitelist what is in the HTTP request ORIGIN header, i.e. typically exactly the hostname that you navigate to in the browser.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I exchanged the IP address with the domain of the site and restarted the bokeh service. Do you want to write an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Glad to hear! It's better for the project if questions are lot left unanswered on SO, so I have added this as an answer.

Comment: For those who are not familiar with HTTP headers much. I was able to fix "Could not open websocket"  problem by running bokeh server with "bokeh serve --allow-websocket-origin=* myapp.py --port 5100" command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I checked the nginx log and there are no errors. allow-websocket-origin is set in the script with kws = {'port': 5100, 'prefix': '/bokeh', 'allow_websocket_origin': ['xxx.xxx.xxx.xx']} with the public IP address of my droplet.

Unless you are ultimately connecting with the literal ip address in the URL bar, that won't work. You need to whitelist what is in the HTTP request ORIGIN header, i.e. typically exactly the hostname that you navigate to in the browser